# Most recent version of Angular JS definition

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Most recent version of Angular JS is 1.2.14 but the most recent version of angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped is 0.9.1.

What does this mean? Are they compatible?

Comment: use the [source](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L1), luke.

Comment: DefinitelyTyped is large project including types for vast majority of JS frameworks. Of course it would't be linked to the version of one of them, it's linked to the version of TS.
And always check for alternative *.d.ts sources because DefintelyTyped defs cant be considered final and stable in most times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DefinitelyTyped version number corresponds to the supported version of TypeScript, not Angular. Most definition files contain the supported version of the target library/framework in the header comment, as does the [Angular definition file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L1).

So the definition file supports `Angular 1.2+` and `TypeScript 0.9.1`.

Comment: Pleasant surprise. :)